# How to unit test the method that schedules an apex schedulable class

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex

I have a method that executes the following code , I am not able to find any thing from CronTrigger to verify the scheduled job

```
public static void ScheduleStatusChk(Id batchId, Set<Id> addressIds, Id accountId, Id documentId){
     CheckBulkStatus chkStatus = new CheckBulkStatus(batchId,addressIds ,accountId,documentId);
    Datetime dt = Datetime.now().addSeconds(30);
    String timeForScheduler = dt.format('s m H d M \'?\' yyyy');
    Id schedId = System.Schedule('Polling for address verification complete' + timeForScheduler, timeForScheduler, chkStatus);}
```

What I tried so far

```
 test.startTest();
            ProcessAddressUpload.PollForVerification(batchProcessId,addressIds,acc.Id,documents[0].Id);
            test.stopTest();
            List<CronTrigger> jobs = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name,CronJobDetail.Id, State FROM CronTrigger  where CronJobDetail.Name Like :'%CheckBulkAddressVerificationStatus%'];
            System.assertEquals(1, jobs.size(), '1 batch job');
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems arlight, is your assert beaking?

Comment: yes , when I do this for a batch I can see it in AsyncApexJob data, but not the CronJob

Answer (score 1):

I made the method being tested return Id for the scheduled job and had to query before test.stopTest() to see the job. The following code worked.

```
test.startTest();
        Id schId =ProcessAddressUpload.PollForVerification(batchProcessId,addressIds,acc.Id,documents[0].Id);
        List<CronTrigger> jobs = [SELECT Id, CronJobDetail.Name,CronJobDetail.Id, State FROM CronTrigger  where  Id = :schId];
        test.stopTest();

        System.assertEquals(1, jobs.size(), '1 batch job');
```